# Unable to load "rails c" (error: "Switch to inspect mode") from within the otherwise functional command line inside of the RubyMine Jetbrains IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, rubymine, rails-console

EDIT: The question is, how to I "switch to inspect mode"?

Through the "External Tools" function within the RubyMine Jetbrains IDE (file, settings, external tools), I have cleverly added a command line to my jetbrains ide. This cmd (I'm using Vista) tool works for all commands, including rails generate and rake commands, but when I try "rails c", well, here's what it looks like:

```
C:\Users\davo\Desktop\RailsProjects\simple_cms>rake db:migrate
rake db:migrate
==  CreateAdminUsersPagesJoin: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:admin_users_pages, {:id=>false})
   -> 0.5620s
-- add_index(:admin_users_pages, ["admin_user_id", "page_id"])
   -> 0.2740s
==  CreateAdminUsersPagesJoin: migrated (0.8360s) =============================


C:\Users\davo\Desktop\RailsProjects\simple_cms>rails c
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
Switch to inspect mode.
```

That's all inside of the jetbrains "custom console". As you can see I was able to do a rake command in there.

I've googled "switch to inspect mode" and wasn't able to find anything very helpful.

Comment: Why don't you use `Tools` | `Run Rails Console...` instead?

Comment: That's essentially the correct answer to this question. Feel free to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyMine has a built-in way to do it: `Tools` | `Run Rails Console...`

Comment: Actually I was wrong about that. When I try to run console commands it gives me the same error: "Switch to inspect mode." I've tried it in all three environments.

Comment: It's not a error, it's just the expected output of the rails console. You can continue typing commands in the console after `>>` and they will run.

Comment: It's slow as hell. Now the windows command line is slow with ruby, but with RubyMine the irb in rails development mode is incredibly, almost prohibitively slow. Is this the case with your version?

Comment: I didn't notice such problems.

Comment: It's working now. thanks. not sure what was going on there for a second.