# Why does rails console command freezes at "Switch to inspect mode."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, railstutorial.org, git-bash

In Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial section 2.3.3 (A user `has_many` microposts), when I typed `rails console` in Git Bash:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
Switch to inspect mode.
```

It freezes at `Switch to inspect mode.` until I typed Ctrl-C.

I browsed through some similar/previous questions to mine but didn't find the solution that I'm looking for:

- [ruby on rails console isn't working, I am getting"Switch to inspect mode" on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836300/ruby-on-rails-console-isnt-working-i-am-gettingswitch-to-inspect-mode-on-win) (It's still resulted in `Switch to inspect mode.` after I ran `$ irb`)
- [Unable to load "rails c" (error: "Switch to inspect mode") from within the otherwise functional command line inside of the RubyMine Jetbrains IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659076/unable-to-load-rails-c-error-switch-to-inspect-mode-from-within-the-other) (I use a combo of Git Bash plus Sublime Text instead of an IDE, such as RubyMine)
- [When I run Rails Console it says "Switch to inspect mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761337/when-i-run-rails-console-it-says-switch-to-inspect-mode) (No answer or best answer so far from this question)

Therefore, how can I bypass `Switch to inspect mode.` and access `rails console`?

**Rails**: 5.0.0.1

**Rails Tutorial**: 4th Edition

**Git for Windows**:  2.9.0.windows.1

**OS**: Windows 7 32-bit Ultimate Service Pack 1

Answer (score 0):

Try using another console:

- problem for me occurred in the 'Git Bash' console (MINGW64)
- solution found with the 'rails console' (command prompt with Ruby on Rails) which works perfectly with irb